# Why Do We Need REACT_APP Prefix in .env File for React Development?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv

There is a statement in
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ :

> Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.

What is meant here by exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name?
I could get nothing from this sentence. Could you please explain this statement with an example?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to read the [linked GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/865#issuecomment-252199527)?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the docs, a React app will include the environment variables in the source code when you build the application.

> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.

Imagine that you have a React frontend and a backend service, both hosted on the same machine. Also imagine that you accidentally refer to an environment variable in your React app, which contains some secret used by the backend service. Now that secret will be exposed to world in the frontend source.

That is why an "intentionally verbose" prefix is added to the environment variables used by the React app. It forces you to be explicit about what you want exposed in the frontend.

> It is intentionally verbose. Otherwise there is a risk of accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that happens to have the same name.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/865#issuecomment-252199527

Comment: Do you suppose React front end and a backend service are in the same directory and we have only one .env file in this directory? If you suppose so then you're right. React App could use the backend service's key by typing process.env.SECRET. If they are not in the same directory and React App doesn't have a .env file then how can React App use process.env.SECRET?