# React.js: Why does accessing my API key from .env file need REACT_APP prefix when using it? I.e. (process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, environment-variables

From my understanding the .env file should hold the API key with the REACT_APP prefix followed by its name and to use the variable we must omit the REACT_APP prefix but I am noticing different behavior in some cases.

I set my env variable in my .env file as say: `REACT_APP_YOUR_KEY_NAME=9999999999999`. And assumed it to be accessed via `process.env.YOUR_KEY_NAME`. Yet I have noticed in some cases (Not Unique) the prefix is required otherwise the key appears to be `undefined`. So it only works when I use `process.env.REACT_APP_YOUR_KEY_NAME`.

```
const FetchData= async () => {
  try {
    const cache = localStorage.getItem('apiData');
    if (cache) {
      return JSON.parse(cache);
    } else {
      const response = await fetch(`${url}?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      localStorage.setItem('gameData', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
      return jsonData;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    return null;
  }
};

export default FetchData;
```

Comment: This this threat answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100830/why-do-we-need-react-app-prefix-in-env-file-for-react-development

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ShueiYang Unfortunately not. Ive gone through the questions but mine is different.

Comment: @AndyDonegan Sorry about that, I have added the code, as generalized as i could make it.

Comment: Ok so it work when you put REACT_APP_... prefix when you use React App as expected if I reread your question, so what's the issue ?

Comment: @ShueiYang Isnt it meant to work without the prefix? I dont understand what changes that it sometimes requires the prefix while other times it works without it.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use REACT_APP_ prefix in env variable names for all custom environment variables in apps created via create-react-app, it's a requirement, if we don't follow the convention, variables will not be accessible, that's it, just like with VITE you will need to put VITE_.. or Nextjs with NEXT_PUBLIC...(only client component)

Also, remember that all the values are accessible on the client-side (browser). You should not use it for any data / credential that your users should not access in the browser and any super secret Api key.

For maximum security it should be used on the backend, and you don't need any prefix on the backend.

For more detail you can (again) check the old documentation on the CRA
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: Im afraid my question is different, my question was meant to be in usage of the variable and not in in declaring it.

Comment: if you have access, than you can do whatever you want with the variable, If it's not what you ask maybe explain it so we can understand your issue ? your question before is asking why we need the prefix, so we answer base on what you ask.

Comment: Ok let me clarify, I really appreciate you taking the time to explain. when we use the variable in our app, should it be accessed with the prefix REACT_APP or without?

Comment: if you work on the frontend using CRA than yea you need to add the prefix to get access as I said on the answer above.

Comment: Alright thank you! I was confused since most documentation said you only need the prefix when declaring it in the env file but not when using it on the front end.